# Trimming an 2d array of int from unwanted values

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an array declared like so:

```
int[,] binaryzacja = new int[bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height];
```

Where it's dimensions are the dimensions of a picture (usually it's gonna be 200x200). A black pixel is represented by 1. All other pixels are represented by 0.

Let's say my array looks like so:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to remove all rows *and* columns that contain only 0.

So, if my example array was 7 columns, 6 rows; I want a new array that will be 5 columns, 3 rows and look like so:

```
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: The rough outline you've given of your code sounds like it would work.  Why don't you show us the code so we can see what might have gone wrong with it?

Comment: How do you fill the array in the first place? Why don't you record it at insertion time for each row and column. for every column a bool, as soon as you do one insert (that is not 0) set it to true. Same for row...

Comment: I just suggest that you add elements of each row or column, if 0 skip it. It is an algorithm problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could transform your `[,]` into a `List`:

```
var list = new List<List<int>>();

for (var i = 0; i < binary.GetLength(0); i++ )
{
    var row = new List<int>();
    for(var j = 0; j < binary.GetLength(1); j++)
        row.Add(binary[i, j]);
    list.Add(row);
}
```

then remove the rows and columns which are all zero:

```
// Remove the rows
list = list.Where(row => row.Contains(1)).ToList();
// Reverse the matrix and apply the same procedure to remove the columns
list = Transpose(list);
list = list.Where(row => row.Contains(1)).ToList();
// Get back the original order of the rows and columns
list = Transpose(list);

static List<List<int>> Transpose(List<List<int>> input)
{
    return input.ElementAt(0).Select((item, index) => 
        {
            var row = new List<int>{input[0][index]};
            input.ForEach(el => row.Add(el.ElementAt(index)));
            return row;
            }).ToList();
        }
}
```

and then transform your resulting list back into a `[,]`.

```
int[,] binaryResult = new int[list.Count(), list.First().Count()];

for (int i = 0; i < binaryResult.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < binaryResult.GetLength(1); j++)
        binaryResult[i, j] = list.ElementAt(i).ElementAt(j);
```

You should extract these into methods, of course.

Comment: What about columns? Besides that, this is so unbelievable inefficient.. Do the young programmers in times of LINQ think about memory usage at all? Creating so many temporary data, list, queries..

Comment: @KonradKokosa, no, for toy projects to be thrown away, for list with tens of elements tops, why would one think about memory? Wouldn't you think about making your code cleaner (supposedly) instead of faster?

Comment: Learning on toy projects is the best opportunity. But still your solution only removes rows so I am very suprised about upvotes...

Comment: @KonradKokosa fixed for columns. I'm surprised as well that nobody mentioned that.

Comment: Downvote removed, as we probably could discuss efficency issue, I upvoted because for sure this is quite elegant and math-oriented approach.. But please, at least add remark,that this creates a lot of temp data so for many many operations on big arrays, more optimized approach might be necessary..

Answer (score 1):

Without fancy stuff:

```
int width = binaryzacja.GetLength(0);
int height = binaryzacja.GetLength(1);

int newWidth = width;
int newHeight = height;

int x, y, x2, y2;

for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    if (IsRowEmpty(binaryzacja, y)) newHeight--;
}

for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    if (IsColumnEmpty(binaryzacja, x)) newWidth--;
}

int[,] binaryzacja2 = new int[newWidth, newHeight];


// copy to new array
for (y2 = y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    if (!IsRowEmpty(binaryzacja, y))
    {
        for(x = x2 = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (!IsColumnEmpty(binaryzacja, x))
            {
                binaryzacja2[x2, y2] = binaryzacja[x, y];
                x2++;
            }
        }
        y2++;
    }
}



bool IsRowEmpty(int[,] array, int y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        if (array[x, y] != 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool IsColumnEmpty(int[,] array, int x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        if (array[x, y] != 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

----- new version:

```
int width = binaryzacja.GetLength(0);
int height = binaryzacja.GetLength(1);

int newWidth = width;
int newHeight = height;

int[] keepRows = new int[height];
int[] keepColumns = new int[width];

int x, y, x2, y2;
int i;

for (i = y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    if (IsRowEmpty(binaryzacja, y)) newHeight--;
    else
    {
        keepRows[i] = y;
        i++;
    }
}

for (i = x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    if (IsColumnEmpty(binaryzacja, x)) newWidth--;
    else
    {
        keepColumns[i] = x;
        i++;
    }
}

int[,] binaryzacja2 = new int[newWidth, newHeight];

// copy to new array
for (y2 = y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    if(y == keepRows[y2])
    {
        for (x2 = x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if(x == keepColumns[x2])
            {
                binaryzacja2[x2, y2] = binaryzacja[x, y];
                x2++;
            }
        }
        y2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit more efficient... About commenting? Is it not almost selfexplaining?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the rows, and keep track of the empty ones in an array of some sort.
Do the same with the columns.

Using this information, create a new array of the proper rows and columns.
Loop through with a double loop. if i is equal to a row in the array, or j is equal to the row in the column, then skip over that value.